# Fixed elements disappear when keyboard opens in Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I created this simple HTML page with a fixed bar at the top and a fixed text element at the bottom. When scrolling, everything stays fixed as intended both at the top and bottom. However, when clicking inside the text field at the bottom, activating the focus and causing the keyboard to appear, if you then scroll, the fixed divs disappear in the Chrome Mobile browser. When you scroll in the opposite direction, they reappear. This behavior wasn't present in earlier Chrome versions. Is it possible to prevent the fixed boxes from collapsing when the focus (keyboard open) is active, or ensure they remain visible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fixed Elements</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    #oben {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    #unten {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    #textbereich {
      width: 95%;
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="oben">
    <p>Here is the fixed content at the top.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 3000px; border: 1px solid; margin: 20px;">text</div>
  <div id="unten">
    <textarea id="textbereich" placeholder="Fixed text area at the bottom"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Proplem

Google Chrome for Mobiles had made this change after version `108` since they saw that this behavior is affecting a lot of users and web developers. It was a real miss to deal with complex UI and popup windows on half, mobile screen. Link below to read their full announcement.

## Solution

They have added a new `meta` tag to bring the old behavior back. It will have the exact intended behavior on newer versions of Chrome. Simply, add this line to your meta tags...

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior/

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I've read and tried it, and it works like a charm for Chrome on Android. I noticed that Chrome on iOS (CriOS) can't change the behavior, because Crios is under Group one, is that correct? Also, thank you for the title suggestion. It might be better to keep the title because I was searching for these specific keywords.

Comment: I'm really glad it worked, but I don't know anything about CriOS. I have never used one and I believe that it may behave the same way as Safari does. This problem may result in similar behaviors on Safari (Haven't been able to test it). After all, those links may help: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-changes-coming-in-chrome-108/ or https://css-tricks.com/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/

Comment: I've been looking for this answer all day)